# How to destroy all subscription Listeners in react naviagation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I added listeners in the react native app using its react navigation. I am using willFocus listener to track the screen focus. It is working fine but I am not able to remove this listener. **How to remove this listener?**.

Some screens are tab based which are not unmounting even when app moves to different stack of navigation. Since componentWillUnmount is not calling therefore unable to remove the listener

```js
componentDidMount(){
  const {navigation} = this.props;
  navigation.addListener ('willFocus', () => {
    //code when screen focused
  })
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  //does not executing when move to stack navigator so unable to remove listner
}
```

```js
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  TabNav: createBottomTabNavigator(
         Tab1: Tab1, 
         Tab2: Tab2,
         Tab3: Tab3
  ),
  screen1: screen1,
  screen2, screen2, 
  screen3: screen3
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NavigationEvents` component from `react-navigation`.

In your render method, you can use this component like this,

```
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
...
...
render(){
 return(
 <View>
    <NavigationEvents
      onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus',payload)}
      onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus',payload)}
      onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur',payload)}
      onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur',payload)}
    />
    {/* 
      Your other code
    */}
  </View>
 )
}
...
```

You can use this method to know whether the screen is focused or not.

For more details see [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html)

Comment: Moving from Tab1 to Tab2, only get 'will focus' & 'did focus', no 'will blur' & 'did blur'. Then Tab2 to Tab1 only 'did focus', then I move to any other screen or tab all the events occur normaly. Why?